# Flexbox height displays as 0px, contains img tags

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm trying to get two images to display in a row, so I'm using a flexbox. I set the box's height to be 500px, but it almost* always calculates to be 0px. It reminds me of the issue with floating elements within, but I've tried this out with img {display:block} and by nesting the img tags in container divs, but neither seem to work.

- = I say "almost" because when viewing on a test page in Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (but not my fiddle) and adjusting the viewport's width, right after the media query flips from the min-width:737px style to the max-width:736px style, the flexbox suddenly has height.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/territorylit/6v4euuwL/

CSS

```
.popup_background {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index:100000000;
}

@media screen and (min-width:737px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width:736px) {

}

.popup_background img.button {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: none;
    z-index:100000001;
    transition:all 0.1s linear;
}

.popup_background img.button:hover {
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:rgba(175,0,175,1);
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-color:rgba(175,0,175,1);
}

    @media screen and (min-width:737px) {
        .popup_background img.button {
            margin-right: calc(5% + 3px);
            margin-top: calc(5% + 3px);
            padding-top:5px;
        }
        .popup_background img.button:hover {
            margin-right: calc(5% + 3px);
            margin-top: calc(5% + 3px);
            border-right-width:3px;
            border-top-width:3px;
            padding-right:3px;
            padding-top:8px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:736px) {
        .popup_background img.button {
            padding-top:5px;
        }
        .popup_background img.button:hover {

        }
    }

.popup_container {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    align-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

    @media screen and (min-width:737px) {
        .popup_container {

            margin-left:5%;
            margin-right:5%;
            margin-top:5%;
            margin-bottom:5%;
            border-width:3px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* grey */
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(10,123,167,0.2); /* cerulean */
        }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width:736px) {
        .popup_container {
            margin-left:3%;
            margin-right:3%;
            margin-top:3%;
            margin-bottom:3%;
            border-width:2px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.9); /* white transparent */
        }
    }

.popup_container.top_heavy {
    justify-content:flex-start;
}


p.chelsea {
    font-family:garamond,serif;
    font-size:1.3em;
}

    @media screen and (min-width:737px) {
        p.chelsea {
            max-width:70%;
            line-height:140%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:736px) {
        p.chelsea {
            height:auto;
            max-width:90%;
            line-height:130%;
        }
    }

p.chelsea.footnote {
    font-family:garamond,serif;
    font-size:1rem;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:1.5rem;
}

    @media screen and (min-width:737px) {
        p.chelsea.footnote {
            width:50%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:736px) {
        p.chelsea.footnote {
            width:90%;
        }
    }

p.chelsea.translation {
    font-size:1.2rem;
    line-height:150%;
}

p.chelsea img {
    width:100%;

}

.milky {
    height:500px;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:flex-start;
    align-content:center;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}

    @media screen and (min-width:737px) {
        .milky {
            width:70%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:736px) {
        .milky {
            width:90%;
        }
    }

#rotation-01 {
    flex:0.6;
}

#rotation-02 {
    flex:1.5686;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section_04" class="section">

    <div class="popup_background">

        <img class="button" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/territory/image/upload/v1461522074/general/hr_grey_50x50.png" onclick="talkPopUpOff(this.id)" id="section_04_off" />

        <div class="popup_container top_heavy">

            <p class="chelsea">&nbsp;</p>

            <div class="milky">
                <img id="rotation-01" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/557a4c2ee4b0fe5a537746b5/t/58b76175bf629a06758f0e2c/1488413284637/milky-way-rotation-1.jpg" />
                <img id="rotation-02" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/557a4c2ee4b0fe5a537746b5/t/58b7618b8419c2a168e77ac6/1488413330003/milky-way-rotation-2.jpg" />
            </div>

            <p class="chelsea">“...in the absence of a bright star near the celestial south pole, Quechua peoples and their ancestors organized the sky by reference to the Milky Way, called Mayu or the “celestial river,” and its apparent cruciform rotations. In a twenty-four-hour period, the Milky Way forms two intersecting intercardinal axes that divide the heavens into quarters. Since the plane of the Milky Way is inclined in relation to the earth’s axis, the stars of one quarter will rise as those of the opposite quarter set as the earth rotates. Astronomical phenomena can be tracked with respect to these quarters, which create a systematic means for the spatial and temporal reckoning of the world and its natural and social rhythms. This principle is central to pre-Columbian spatial reckoning.”</p>

            <p class="chelsea footnote">Gartner, William Gustav. "6· Mapmaking in the Central Andes." <em>Americas</em> 169 (1970): 647-54.</p>

            <p class="chelsea">&nbsp;</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `min-height: 500px` seems to work.

Comment: Removing `overflow: hidden` from `.milky` solves the problem. I'll write you an answer if I can ever figure out why.

Comment: `z-index:100000000;` is a bit overkill, no? Haha

Comment: @MatheusAvellar I'm working with Squarespace and they have stuff stratified at some pretty silly z-indices I need to make sure I leapfrog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is that `.popup_container` is a flexbox.**

Simply change `.popup_container` to `display: block`, take the `height` off of `.milky`, and I believe it will behave as you would like.

**Why?**

The items within the `.popup_container` flexbox (such as your content, images, and footnote) automatically try to share all the vertical space, which is 100% of the display height, since *`.popup_container` is a descendant of `.popup_background`, which has `height: 100%`.* However, there is an exception. For some reason (if anyone knows why I'll be glad to include it), the text content takes precedence over the flexbox with the images. While the text gets to use up all the space it needs, the flexbox is reduced to barely anything. Your `height` property on the flexbox is obsolete because it is, itself, a flexbox item.

Also note: it's bad practice to have a fixed element the child of a fixed element, which is what you currently have. The inner element doesn't need to be fixed at all.

Comment: I understand this nuance and your solution works well, thank you. FYI: I haven't touched the fiddle since I posted.

Comment: Ok, I removed my edit. I was using a different computer, so things must have just looked different. Also, from the [SO Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): "If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer" ;)